# Jenkins Parameterized Build with Jenkinsfile from SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have some jenkins pipeline jobs defined with Jenkinsfile's located in bitbucket server, [as described here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#defining-a-pipeline-in-scm). These builds are parameterized, and we'd like to be able to manually run them with non-default parameters.

The problem is, since the Jenkinsfile isn't checked out until we run it, the first time we run the build the build button is just "Build Now" instead of "Build with Parameters". Currently we are running it once with the default values so that it fails, and then running it again with the "Build with Parameters" button so we can pass in what we want.

Obviously not ideal. What is the right way to do this so we can run it with custom parameters the first time?

Comment: Are you defining the parameters inside of the Jenkinsfile or by the web interface in Job properties block?

Comment: Inside the Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible currently, as they are post-processed they need to be executed in the 1st run before being known to jenkins and being available as 'Build with parameters'. Issue tracked here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41929

There are various ways to handle this,
The first is as you have alluded to, run it automatically/manually and let it fail, though maybe if you could set working defaults so it at least succeeds?

Another option, is to evaluate if this is the first run or not, and if so, execute the Jenkins job skipping all steps and purely processing the parameters.

Comment: Did you maybe mean "this is not possible currently"?